# issue with WPF combobox selectionchanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have my logic of opening a search modal window based on user selection in a combobox. What happens is the modal window opens but the selected item is not reflected in the combobox. i.e Unlike a Windows form, the WPF combobox is not reflecting the newly selected item when the selectionchanged event is fired.

well i would have used the SelectionChangeCommitted in a Winform, i am not finding an equivalent in this case. Am i missing something thats obvious? Thanks!

Comment: i was thinking "should i create a dependency property and bind it to selectedItem and have a call back for property changed???"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening the modal window in the context of the selecteditemchanged event of the combo box?  I would recommend opening the modal window using the dispatcher.  This will give the bindings time to catch up if that is the issue.  Are you binding the selected item of the combo box to a property on a model / view model?  If so is this a one way or two way bind?

It would help if you posted some code along with your question.

Comment: for now its a one way binding to the Source. view on selection changed event calls the presenter method to open the search window which is a modal. i was thinking of dispatcher.. but isnt it a real world scenario where ppl might wanna do it like in the Winform way! was seriously wondering y is there not a SelectionChangeCommitted equivalent. I was hoping i missed noting the equivalent! i can post some code to explain further, when i get back to my computer!

Comment: you can get what i really mean.. have a wpf window, data bind some values to a combobox, then on selectionChanged event call MessageBox.Show("Changed") you will notice the combobox hasnt updated the newly selected value yet when the messagebox is shown to u!

Comment: Yes - by using the dispatcher and setting the priority correctly the combo box will update before the message box is shown.

Comment: Thanks Tsells. but couldnt wrap my head around the reason why it is behaving so in WPF. If you have any explanation plz share across :) for now marking it as answer!

Comment: It has to do with event timing.  The change event is already in the process of being executed - and calling a dialog box from that doesn't allow the event to complete and perform all actions associated with the event (such as updating a value) if a message box opens first - so launching with the dispatcher effectively delays the launch of the dialog until after the event operation completes.